# sqoop vs unload command

Tags: hdfs, sqoop

Using the unload command in any database, we can get the data into a flat file and we can copy that to HDFS.
What is the advantage of using sqoop over unload command **in this regard**?
Please explain. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop will translate data with the type of you DB to a Java type wich can be then used on a process. Sqoop also allow you to offload various relationnal db to Hive or Hbase. Or it will provide a parquet output ( one of the most used format for datasets under hadoop )

Sqoop will also split and distribute the export file folowing a provided key.